# SSIS C# Async SQL Queries hang (including executing stored procedures)

Tags: c#, sql-server, asynchronous, ssis, async-await

So I've been trying to solve this particular problem of mine for awhile, looking up similar issues on here but unfortunately haven't been able to find anything quite the same.

I'd like to preface this that it's my first delve into attempting async programming in C#.

I'm currently trying to execute a set of stored procedures in a SQL server database asynchronously and log the start and end times. I'm doing this with a C# Script Task in SSIS. I've tested this process using test procedures that simply populate a dummy table with numbers and it's worked great. However, when it comes to executing the actual stored procedures (some of which are intensive) some faster procedures run but after a few (usually around the same 6-7) it hangs. There are a total of 13 tasks (procedures).

Additionally, I've set the IsolationLevel on the Script Task (and all other components within the package) to ReadUncommitted. I've tried setting it to Snapshot but it appears my version of BIDS doesn't support this method (or some installation component is missing).

Here's a snippet of my code (some declarations have been snipped out for brevity):

```
            // Declarations
            Queue<string> procedureQueue = CreateProcedureQueue(procedureTable);
            int counter = procedureQueue.Count;                                

            Task<int>[] Tasks = new Task<int>[counter];

            using (OleDbConnection activeConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {

                activeConnection.Open();

                // Async Task iteration
                for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                {
                    Tasks[i] = Task.Run(async () => await ProcedureTask(procedureQueue.Dequeue(), activeConnection));
                }

                // Wait for Task completion
                try
                {
                    Task.WaitAll(Tasks);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw e;
                }

            }

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            // Return component result
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
        }

    }

    private async Task<int> ProcedureTask(string procedureName, OleDbConnection activeConnection)
    {

        // Declarations //
        string loggingTableName = (string)Dts.Variables["$Project::MonthlyFactSPs_TableName"].Value;

        string CommandText = 
        "update " + loggingTableName + " set last_execution_time = getdate() " +
            "where stored_procedure_schema + '.' + stored_procedure_name = '" + procedureName.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "") + "';" +
        "EXEC " + procedureName + " WITH RECOMPILE;" +
        "update " + loggingTableName + " set last_completion_time = getdate() " +
            "where stored_procedure_schema + '.' + stored_procedure_name = '" + procedureName.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "") + "';";

        // Create new command //
        using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(CommandText, activeConnection))
        {
            // Set command parameters //
            command.CommandTimeout = 1200;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;                

            try
            {                    
                return await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            }
            catch (OleDbException e)
            {
                Dts.Events.FireError(e.ErrorCode, "[" + DateTime.Now + "]" + procedureName + " execution", "Query failed to execute due to: " + e.Message, "", 0);
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
```

Any ideas? Is there some fundamental I'm not grasping correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a deadlock somewhere... If you remove the logging does that make a difference?  perhaps that is causing a deadlock?

Comment: you're launching a bunch of sql operations in parallel, on different connection instances; is it simply possible that they're locking and/or deadlocking each other? if this is SQL Server (tags), have you tried running `sp_who` / `sp_who2` to see if they're blocked? Frankly, I would suggest "serial" rather than "parallel" here, but that's up to you. Side note: *please* use parameters - that `update` statement is *horrible*; additional side note: if you're using SQL Server, `SqlConnection` would usually be recommended over `OleDbConnection`.

Comment: oh; edit to the above - it looks like you're actually passing the *same* connection each time - in which case: is this "MARS" enabled? if not, we should *expect* most of them to fail - you aren't *meant* to issue concurrent operations on a single connection unless "MARS" is enabled; and even if you do: that doesn't make them truly parallel - it makes them *pipelined*

Comment: @GPW It's definitely the procedure execution that is causing the problem as removing that but just logging works absolutely fine.

Comment: @MarcGravell I tried using a single connection instead of multiple to avoid deadlocking, as I was running into that issue previously. MARS wasn't enabled, thank you for that, I've added the argument.

If I continue to run into the same issue I'll try again with multiple connections.

The update statement I'll tidy up at a later point once I've got everything working, for now it's just quick and dirty.

Comment: Just re-ran with MARS enabled and am now getting the deadlock error messages reported. Thanks for your help guys - am now trying to resolve the deadlocks.

Have removed the logging statements like @GPW suggested and testing again.

Comment: Besides `IsolationLevel` of your *Script Task*, check that  `TransactionOption=Supported` on the task. This setting has little to do with built-in transactions of SQL Server, it uses transactions handled by MS Distributed Transaction Coordinator.

Comment: I recommend you to convert this code to SQL script task with ForEach loop inside ControlFlow

Comment: @YasharAliabasi That will only work synchronously which is why we didn't go for it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue - it was caused by the destination table's lock escalation being set to AUTO, which was escalating row exclusive locks to table exclusive locks.

Thanks for the help everyone.